# Neo4j Relationship name

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

Could you tell me how to pass the contents of a variable as a relation name in Neo4j?

My code is:

```
CREATE (a)-[r:{linkParam}]->(b)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to options:

(1) Concatenate the string client-side, i.e. create a query string JavaScript that already has the relationship type (e.g. `"CREATE (a)-[r:"  + linkParam + "]->(b)"`. Note that this might introduce [SQL injection-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities in your system.

(2) Use the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/):

```
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, {linkParam}, b)
```

This creates a relationship with a dynamic type.

Note that for Neo4j 3.2+, you can use the [new parameter syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-introduction), i.e. `$linkParam` instead of `{linkParam}`.